# Is the Adobe Flash plugin the only way two people can video-chat, using a web browser?

Tags: flash, html, browser, adobe, camera

if two people want to video chat using a web browser and their camera's, is Adobe Flash the only plugin available? Yes, there are other 3rd party plugins, but those all have to be manually downloaded. So only using what is baked into the common browsers, is Flash the only way this is possible?

Also - HTML5 browsers** are acceptable .. so that might help someone answer this question. I understand there's so many browsers and browser versions, so lets just say the latest versions at the time of this post - no IE6, etc.

** Not sure if HTML5 spec for `video` is just for playback or both playback and interaction with camera's.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the WebSocket technology to stream data to the browser. so this part of video chat would be covered.

the camera interaction is not implemented yet: you can check it here: http://caniuse.com/#search=camera

Comment: so in HTML5 there is a wish to provide video/audio streaming with a StreamAPI (http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dnd.html#stream-api) .. but this hasn't been official locked down .. and not yet implimented by any browser. Is that correct?